# Service Worker returns "site can not be reached" on only one device

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've been making a progressive web app.

I've registered a service worker for offline access. However, in doing so, I seem to have blocked access somehow for one android device, which says "This site cannot be reached" when visiting it.

Accessing it from a computer or another device works fine.

I wondered if the problematic device is trying to access a now outdated service worker/cache.

I've tried clearing the cache on the Chrome app but still have the same problem.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Find out the browser version. Use that info to research what PWA features are available.

Comment: If I go incognito, it works fine, so I don't think it's got anything to do with the browser being out of date